# Why does my iPhone X 11.2 emulator keep crashing when testing my .iOS app in Xamarin?

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, emulation

So I am pretty new to Xamarin and i have been messing around with the .iOS side in VS more and have tried using buttonClicks and TapGestures with Labels and Buttons, but something weird happens. When i click on the Button or Label my IOS emulator crashes and instead of showing what happens in the clickevent it crashes and turns to a black screen with spinning white dots. Does anyone have an idea why this happens! This following block of code, is a small program where i create a label and have a click event that once clicked it disappears. So when i click on the label my emulator crashes.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Fruits
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StackLayout st = new StackLayout
        {
            Padding = new Thickness(5, Device.OnPlatform(iOS: 20, Android: 0, WinPhone: 0), 5, 0)
        };

        this.Content = st;

        Label one = new Label
        {
            Text = "Watermelon",
            IsVisible = true,


        };
        st.Children.Add(one);
        var tapped = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tapped.Tapped += (s, e) =>
        {
            one.IsVisible = false;
        };
        one.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapped);


    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your code looks no problem ,  is there any crash message?

Comment: no there isnt any crash message, the emulator after the click of the label just turns black with the spinning dots and it never comes back

Comment: try to run the emulator on mac or test on a real device .